# Jenkins: When I build and archive an ios app, the file "myapp.app" does not show up under "Last successful artifacts"

Tags: ios, jenkins, artifact

I have jenkins jobs to build android AND ios apps. This runs on a MAC.

After the build the apps should be archived. This works ok for the android "myapp.apk" file. It will be listed under "last successful artifacts".

For ios however the file "myapp.app" is not shown.
In the jenkins configuration the file is specified as "jenkins/jobs/ios/myapp.app/**/*.*"

I can always find the last successful artifact. But I have to download it as a zip file and unzip the app. This is not really handy. I would like to be able to click on "myapp.app" to download it in one go.

I presume the problem has something to do with the fact that the app file is also a directory on the MAC.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: did you found a better solution for it? thanks

Comment: can you show me what is your script or jenkins configuration?